# A limit to zero, evaluating infinities

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$ \displaystyle \frac{ds}{dr} = \frac{(1-\theta)}{\theta} \frac{( 1 + r )^{1/\theta - 2}\left[ (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} \right] }{\left( (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} + (1+r)^{(1-\theta)/\theta} \right)^2} $$
>
> $$ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{(1-\theta)}{\theta} \frac{ ( 1 + r )^{1/\theta - 2}\left[ (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} \right] }{\left( (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} + (1+r)^{(1-\theta)/\theta} \right)^2}  = 0 $$

$r$ is the interest rate and $\rho$ is the discount rate.  If $r=\rho \Rightarrow$ limit does not exist, if $r \neq \rho \Rightarrow$ wolfram alpha says the limit is zero.

How does this change lead to different Answers?  Further, with $r=\rho$ the graph made shows

$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0^-} = - \infty $$

$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0^+} = \infty $$

Changing the equation to: $r \neq \rho$:

Same graph as above *and* a point at the origin.

Usually since the limts do not agree we may conclude $\theta \to 0$ does not exist as the two sides are not equivalent.  But there is that point at the origin, ideas on how that is there?

Comment: If $r>0$ and $\rho>0$ are fixed and $\theta\to0$ with $\theta>0$ then the limit is not zero, try for example the limit when $r=\rho$.

Comment: Yes agreed @Did, I believe the limit with these conditions is positive infinity.  and the limit to zero from the left is negative infinity.  But in wolfram alpha it shows these in addition to a singular point at the origin.  I am curious to this point.

Comment: Oh the point only showed up when I took $r=0.02, \rho = 0.01$, or in general $r \neq \rho$ and doesn't with $r=\rho$, must be something about this

Comment: Oh, and would it *kill* you to include this information in the post?

Comment: Okay, sorry I did not realise when I posted they needed to be not equal

Answer (score 0):

A friend calculated this:

$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{(1-\theta)/\theta ( 1 + r )^{1/\theta - 2}\left[ (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} \right] }{\left( (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} + (1+r)^{(1-\theta)/\theta} \right)^2} $$

$$ = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{(1-\theta)/\theta ( 1 + r )^{1/\theta - 2}\left[ (1+\rho)^{1/\theta} \right] }{\left( (1+\rho)^{2/\theta} + (1+r)^{2(1-\theta)/\theta} + 2(1+\rho)^{1/\theta}(1+r)^{(1-\theta)/\theta} \right)} $$

Divide through by $(1+r)^{1/\theta} (1+\rho)^{1/\theta}$

$$ \displaystyle = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{(1-\theta)/\theta (1+r)^{-2}}{\left( \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} \right)^{1/\theta} + \frac{(1+r)^{2/\theta - 2}}{(1+r)^{1/\theta} (1+\rho)^{1/\theta}} + 2 \frac{(1+r)^{(1-\theta)/\theta}}{(1+r)^{1/\theta}} } $$

$$ \displaystyle = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{(1-\theta)/\theta (1+r)^{-2}}{\left( \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} \right)^{1/\theta} + \frac{1}{(1+r)^2} \left( \frac{1+r}{1+\rho} \right)^{1/\theta} + 2 (1+r)^{-1} } $$

$$ \displaystyle = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{(1-\theta)/\theta}{ (1+r)^{2} \left( \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} \right)^{1/\theta} + \left( \frac{1+r}{1+\rho} \right)^{1/\theta} + 2 (1+r) } $$

Then use $L'hospital's$ rule

$$ \displaystyle = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{d\theta} (1-\theta)/\theta}{ \frac{d}{d\theta} \left[ (1+r)^{2} \left( \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} \right)^{1/\theta} + \left( \frac{1+r}{1+\rho} \right)^{1/\theta} + 2 (1+r) \right]} $$

$$ = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{ - 1/\theta^2 }{ (1+r)^{2} \left( - \frac{1}{\theta^2} \right) \left( \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} \right)^{1/\theta} \log{ \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} } + \left( - \frac{1}{\theta^2} \right) \left( \frac{1+r}{1-\rho} \right)^{1/\theta} \log{ \frac{1+r}{1-\rho} } + 0 } $$

$$ = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{ 1 }{ (1+r)^{2} \left( \frac{1+\rho}{1-r} \right)^{1/\theta} \log{\frac{1+\rho}{1-r} } + \left( \frac{1+r}{1-\rho} \right)^{1/\theta} \log{ \frac{1+r}{1-\rho} } } $$

When $ \frac{1+\rho}{1+r} < 0 $ have

$$ \frac{1}{0 + \infty} = 0 $$

And $ \frac{1+\rho}{1+r} > 0 $

$$ \frac{1}{\infty + 0} = 0 $$

But still diverges for $r = \rho$

Which would prove what we want.  But isn't with either inequality don't obtain just infinity, so looking at the second inequality greater than zero, that is:

$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0^-} \left( \frac{1+\rho}{1+r} \right)^{1/\theta} = 0 $$

$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0^+} \left( \frac{1+\rho}{1+r} \right)^{1/\theta} = \infty $$

So we are closer but I think still can't conclude the limit is zero.